# Process won't start in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

So, I have a simple screen that registers the saves made in various text files (this is what I call **"escenario"**. I can haveseveral escenarios for the important changes made to the files, and later on, if I want to return to a past escenario, I just load the files I saved. That works great, but my problem is when I try to start the process of the .exe for the python code that makes the copies of the files.

```
protected void AddItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = 0;
        int totalItems = escenario_list.Items.Count;
            if (totalItems > 0){
                string esc = "Escenario ";
                num = totalItems + 1;
                var x = esc + num.ToString();
                var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                var str = x + " - " + date;
                escenario_list.Items.Add(new ListItem(str, num.ToString()));
                Process.Start(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdministracionEscenarios\bin\MoveFiles\MoveFiles.exe");
            }
            else if(totalItems == 0){
                string esc = "Escenario ";
                num = 1;
                var x = esc + num.ToString();
                var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                var str = x + " - " + date;
                escenario_list.Items.Add(new ListItem(str, num.ToString()));
                Process.Start(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdministracionEscenarios\bin\MoveFiles\MoveFiles.exe");
            }
    }
```

So `Process.Start` just won't start that .exe file. What can be the reason?? I'm also using `using System.Diagnostics;` at the beggining, so that's not the issue here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're referencing your local drive on the server.  Use this method instead Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/MoveFiles/"), "MoveFiles.exe");  The HostingEnvironment will reference the directory on the server.  You've been referencing the customer's local directory and not the server's local directory

Also, download and launch process explorer, and go to Find and Find Handle.  Run your program and search for the MoveFiles.exe file.  This will ensure that your application has executed on the server.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not. The users logs in the same server where I have this web application. that's why I always put the complete path. The final screen gets applied in a system called MPlanner, that uses localhost to load several ASP pages made for it.

Comment: I would download that processes explorer to see if the application is opening during the debug.  This will tell you if the client's session attempted to open the file, but doesn't have administrator privileges, or it opened with an error

Comment: I used another option: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "", "additem()", true);` to start a javascript that makes an ActiveXObject. Thanks for your help.